# Firebase : Unable to add new app (Error status : RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED)

Tags: firebase

I have a firebase project with 24 apps (android and ios) for push notification.
Now I tried to add a new ios app for push notifications.
It shows an error. By inspecting the browser and network section I get a response message.

> {
>     "error": {
>       "code": 429,
>       "message": "com.google.apps.framework.request.CanonicalCodeException: Reached limit on number of clients in this project. Code: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED\ncom.google.net.rpc3.RpcException: \u003ceye3 title='/ClientAuthConfig.CreateClient, RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED'/\u003e APPLICATION_ERROR;google.identity.clientauthconfig.v1/ClientAuthConfig.CreateClient;com.google.apps.framework.request.CanonicalCodeException: Reached limit on number of clients in this project. Code: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED;AppErrorCode=8;StartTimeMs=1502806165337;tcp;Deadline(sec)=14.993;ResFormat=UNCOMPRESSED;Originator=traffic-prod;Tag=\u0002cidc\u00032;ServerTimeSec=0.08908416;LogBytes=256;Non-FailFast;EffSecLevel=privacy_and_integrity;DelegatedRole=mobilesdk-devrel-frontend;ReqFormat=UNCOMPRESSED;ReqID=87cb8bb02f3e3577;GlobalID=d91b66b01c039b56;Server=[2002:a17:902:44c::]:9875",
>       "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED",
>       "details": [
>         {
>           "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.internal.firebase.v1.ErrorCode"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }

What is that..?

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/AJWkjyajIFE

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the error message is quite clear:

> Reached limit on number of clients in this project

According to [this statement](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/ltmyg5e9jAA/6V1CnhJ9AQAJ), the exact number of free projects you can create is measured by your reputation and starts with a number around 20.

You can either switch to a paid plan or delete some of your existing projects to create new ones.

Comment: The statement you link is for the number of projects, which indeed has always been limited. But this error occurs for the number of apps in a project, which seems to be a recently introduced limit.